# Identify abrasive pad

Tags: product-support

I am trying to find a part number for this pad ( see attached). 4" wide, 6" long, 1.3" thick. Very coarse.

I know this is a weird question and will probably be closed. Anyways, we have used those, but do not have the original box, and do not know where it came from. I did a google picture search and nothing matched. I contacted McMaster Carr and 3M, but they didn't know. Maybe someone knows and has a comment before this is closed.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I also checked with MSC and Grainger. Maybe someone knows another manufacturer who makes those "scotch brite" pads.

Comment: Air you sure it's an abrasive pad & not a filter? What type of material does it appear to be made of: plastic/polymer, steel wool, metal shavings, ... ?

Comment: No, it's not a filter. It's plastic with possibly some coating. It's like a scotch brite pad but super coarse.

Comment: Wow that is really coarse. That looks like its a like a grit of 2 or something lol.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Scotchbrite abrasive hand pad in an extra-coarse grade.

[image]

see the 3M website at [https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/All-3M-Products/Abrasives/Industrial-Abrasives-Finishing/Hand-Pads/?N=5002385+8692962+8710644+8710812+8710964+8711017+3294857497&rt=r3](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/%7E/All-3M-Products/Abrasives/Industrial-Abrasives-Finishing/Hand-Pads/?N=5002385+8692962+8710644+8710812+8710964+8711017+3294857497&rt=r3)

Comment: Thank you Niels, but I don't see it. I contacted 3M earlier and they could not identify it.